# How to segregate files in the date based directory using MapReduce program?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have huge `number(~100 thousands)` of small log files(with `timestamp` in the file name),
 e.g. `data-1412719255508-02174-ip-10-1-1-59-rowid.log`.
 Now I want to put these files in the date based directories.
 For example, log files with timestamp corresponding to the date `2014-10-06` should go into the `/raw/logs/2014-10-06/` directory and so on.
 Also, these files are of small `size(~1-10mb)` and that's why I want to `merge` them as well.

I want to write a map reduce program in Java for this purpose. I am looking for some idea or example.

Comment: Are the raw files lying on hdfs?

Comment: No. raw files are in a local file system.